# What is the meaning of соплежуйство?

Tags: сленг, semantics

I understand that соплежуйство is a compound noun literally meaning chewing on snots, but what is the figurative meaning of this word in Russian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тянуть время; медлить; бездействовать

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сопли_жевать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)